# Equivalence partitioning in a different format

Tags: equivalence-partition

I found the following example question, but not sure, what is the theory behind this.

[image: decision testing]

Comment: I must be stupid, but this question seems too miss info. What do the axis mean? What do the numbers mean, what does X mean? Seems like a big riddle. Does the question have more info? Do you want us the answer it?

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal : No, I wouldn't like to get the solution, but the theory, how can I solve it.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 variables: *Salary* and *number of children*.

*Salary* has two possible values: (Less than 20.000) or (20.000 or more)

*Number of children* has two possible values: (more than 2 children) or (2 children or less).

Two variables, two values each => 2*2 rows in a Truth Table.

Only when *Salary* is (Less than 20.000) there will be recalculations.
And when *Salary* is (Less than 20.000) **and** *Number Of Children** is (More than 2 children) there will be re-calculation + 10% reduction.

Extra: Of course, additional questions must be asked:

- What's the definition of "children"? 18 years old or below? 16? Just a descendent?
- Do they need to be alive?
- Adopted and forster children count?
- 20.000 is only full employment salary or other sorts of income count too?

[image]